# Evaluate the triple integral where G is the solid.

Tags: calculus

> To Find: Evaluate the triple integral where G is the solid enclosed by the line $z=y$, the $xy$ - plane and the parabolic cylinder $y=1-x^2$

$$\iiint_G y\,dV$$

> where we have a cylinder $y=1-x^2$ , a bottom $z=0$, bounded on the top by the plane $x=y$

$$\mathbb{R}=\left \{  (x,y,z):(x,y)\epsilon A, 0\le z\le y\right \}$$

$$\mathbf{A}=\left\{(x,y): -1 \le x\le 1, 0 \le y \le 1-x^2\right \}$$

$$\iiint_Gy\,dV=\iint_A \int_0^yy\,dz\,dA$$

$$=\iint_A\left.\frac{1}{2}y^2\right|_0^y\,dA$$

$$=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{1-x^2}\frac{1}{2}y^2 \,dy\,dx$$

> but where to from here?

$$=\int_{-1}^1\left.\frac{1}{6}y^3\right|_0^{1-x^2}\,dx$$

$$=\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1-x^{2}){^3}}{6}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}(\left.-\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{3x^5}{5}-x^3+x\right|_{-1}^{+1})$$

$$=\frac{1}{6}(\frac{-2}{7}+\frac{6}{5})$$

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the question, as the given region is unbounded above. Indeed, for any $z^* > 0$, we have that $(0, 0.5, z^*) \in G$.

Comment: Why do you think you region is bounded by the planes $x=-1$ and $x=1$?

Comment: @Guilherme Thompson Yes indeed there was a typo -  it should read $z=y$ not $x=y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I think there's could be something wrong with you integration limits, but I'll assume then true.
So, let's start
$$I=\int_{G} y \, \mathrm{d}V.$$
Using you definitions
$$G=\left\{v=(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: -1 \leq x 1,\, 0 \leq y \leq 1-x^2,\, 0 \leq z \leq y  \right\}$$
Then
\begin{align}
I&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} y \mathbb{1}_{\left\{v\in G\right\}} \, \mathrm{d}V
%
\\&= \int_{-1}^1 \left(\int_0^{1-x^2} \left(\int_0^y y \, \mathrm{d}z\right) \, \mathrm{d}y\right) \, \mathrm{d}x
%
\\&= \int_{-1}^1 \left(\int_0^{1-x^2} \left[z y \vphantom{\int_0^y}\right]_{z=0}^{z=y} \, \mathrm{d}y\right) \, \mathrm{d}x
%
\\&= \int_{-1}^1 \left(\int_0^{1-x^2} y^2 \, \mathrm{d}y\right) \, \mathrm{d}x
%
\\&= \int_{-1}^1 \left[\frac{y^3}{3} \vphantom{\int_0^y} \right]_{y=0}^{y=1-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
%
\\&= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\left(1-x^2\right)^3}{3}  \, \mathrm{d}x
%
\\&=  \left[\frac{1}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^5-\frac{1}{21}x^7 \vphantom{\int_{-1}^1} \right]_{x=1}^{x=-1}
\\&=\frac{32}{105}.
\end{align}